# failed to pull and unpack image "registry.k8s.io/pause:3.6" when update the kubernetes pod

Tags: kubernetes, containers

When I update the kubernetes(`v1.28.3`) image, I found the pod could not fetch the pause image:

```
│   Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  10m                    kubelet            Failed to create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to get sandbox image "registry.k8s.io/pause:3.6": fail │
│ ed to pull image "registry.k8s.io/pause:3.6": failed to pull and unpack image "registry.k8s.io/pause:3.6": failed to resolve reference "registry.k8s.io/pause:3.6": failed to do request: Head "https://u │
│ s-west2-docker.pkg.dev/v2/k8s-artifacts-prod/images/pause/manifests/3.6": dial tcp 142.251.8.82:443: i/o timeout                                                                                          │
│   Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  6m20s                  kubelet            Failed to create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = DeadlineExceeded desc = failed to get sandbox image "registry.k8s.io/pause:3 │
│ .6": failed to pull image "registry.k8s.io/pause:3.6": failed to pull and unpack image "registry.k8s.io/pause:3.6": failed to resolve reference "registry.k8s.io/pause:3.6": failed to do request: Head " │
│ https://us-west2-docker.pkg.dev/v2/k8s-artifacts-prod/images/pause/manifests/3.6": dial tcp 173.194.174.82:443: i/o timeout                                                                               │
│   Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  3m23s                  kubelet            Failed to create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to get sandbox image "registry.k8s.io/pause:3.6": fail │
│ ed to pull image "registry.k8s.io/pause:3.6": failed to pull and unpack image "registry.k8s.io/pause:3.6": failed to resolve reference "registry.k8s.io/pause:3.6": failed to do request: Head "https://u │
│ s-west2-docker.pkg.dev/v2/k8s-artifacts-prod/images/pause/manifests/3.6": dial tcp 173.194.174.82:443: i/o timeout                                                                                        │
│   Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  2m38s (x4 over 8m30s)  kubelet            Failed to create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = DeadlineExceeded desc = failed to get sandbox image "registry.k8s.io/pause:3 │
│ .6": failed to pull image "registry.k8s.io/pause:3.6": failed to pull and unpack image "registry.k8s.io/pause:3.6": failed to resolve reference "registry.k8s.io/pause:3.6": failed to do request: Head " │
│ https://us-west2-docker.pkg.dev/v2/k8s-artifacts-prod/images/pause/manifests/3.6": dial tcp 142.251.8.82:443: i/o timeout                                                                                 │
│   Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  115s                   kubelet            Failed to create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to get sandbox image "registry.k8s.io/pause:3.6": fail │
│ ed to pull image "registry.k8s.io/pause:3.6": failed to pull and unpack image "registry.k8s.io/pause:3.6": failed to resolve reference "registry.k8s.io/pause:3.6": failed to do request: Head "https://u │
│ s-west2-docker.pkg.dev/v2/k8s-artifacts-prod/images/pause/manifests/3.6": dial tcp 64.233.188.82:443: i/o timeout                                                                                         │
│   Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  28s (x9 over 12m)      kubelet            Failed to create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = DeadlineExceeded desc = failed to get sandbox image "registry.k8s.io/pause:3 │
│ .6": failed to pull image "registry.k8s.io/pause:3.6": failed to pull and unpack image "registry.k8s.io/pause:3.6": failed to resolve reference "registry.k8s.io/pause:3.6": failed to do request: Head " │
│ https://us-west2-docker.pkg.dev/v2/k8s-artifacts-prod/images/pause/manifests/3.6": dial tcp 64.233.188.82:443: i/o timeout
```

The kubernetes cluster facing some issue when fetch the pause image. I have already tried to pull the image and rename the image like this:

```
ctr -n=k8s.io image pull k8s.m.daocloud.io/pause:3.6
ctr -n=k8s.io images tag k8s.m.daocloud.io/pause:3.6 registry.k8s.io/pause:3.6
```

this way works for a peroid of time, when I update the pod next time, the error will facing again. what should I do to fixed this issue perminantly? I have already tried to add `--pod-infra-container-image`:

```
[root@k8sslave01 ~]# ps aux|grep kubelet
root      1898  1.7  4.5 1986720 88968 ?       Ssl   2023 1196:30 /usr/bin/kubelet --bootstrap-kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/bootstrap-kubelet.conf --kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf --config=/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml --container-runtime-endpoint=unix:///var/run/containerd/containerd.sock --pod-infra-container-image=registry.aliyuncs.com/google_containers/pause:3.9
root      6076  0.0  0.1 112796  2000 pts/1    S+   15:38   0:00 grep --color=auto kubelet
```

seems did not work. This is the containderd config:

```
[root@k8sslave01 kubelet]# cat /etc/containerd/config.toml
#   Copyright 2018-2022 Docker Inc.

#   Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
#   you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
#   You may obtain a copy of the License at

#       http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

#   Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
#   distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
#   WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
#   See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
#   limitations under the License.

#disabled_plugins = ["cri"]

#root = "/var/lib/containerd"
#state = "/run/containerd"
#subreaper = true
#oom_score = 0
[plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry]
   config_path = "/etc/containerd/certs.d"

[plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri"]
  sandbox_image = "k8s.m.daocloud.io/pause:3.6"

#[grpc]
#  address = "/run/containerd/containerd.sock"
#  uid = 0
#  gid = 0

#[debug]
#  address = "/run/containerd/debug.sock"
#  uid = 0
#  gid = 0
#  level = "info"
```

Comment: Looks like the root cause of the errors  is  **/var partition** may have sufficient free space **(check with df -h)**, but during the upgrading process, once new version images are loaded but before old version images are erased, it may become over 80% used. This may be the primary source of the issue.





As a result, Kubernetes may **"clean up"** or **"garbage collect"** images that it identifies as not being used, including the necessary inactive "pause"** image.

Comment: To resolve the issue in the short term:

Try this recommended  image download from here [https://download.vmturbo.com/appliance/download/updates/cisco/pause.tar](https://download.vmturbo.com/appliance/download/updates/cisco/pause.tar)

Later follow steps as mentioned in this IBM [doc.](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/pods-fail-become-ready-following-offline-upgrade-stuck-containercreating)

Comment: how to avoid the kubelet garbage collect the pause image.

Comment: this answser told what what may cause this issue, but the solution are not perfect. I am still searching for some perfect way to fixed this, change the pause image address with another accessable url or mark the pause image not to be garbage collect by kubelet. @SaiChandiniRouthu

Comment: Just updated my answer. Have a look at the **EDIT1** section. Which may help to resolve your issue

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the root cause of the errors  is  **/var partition** may have sufficient free space **(check with df -h)**, but during the upgrading process, once new version images are loaded but before old version images are erased, it may become over 80% used. This is the primary source of the issue.

As a result, Kubernetes may **"clean up"** or **"garbage collect"** images that it identifies as not being used, including the necessary but inactive **"pause"** image.

**As per this Medium**  **[blog](https://medium.com/@reefland/cri-purge-kubernetes-cleanup-of-cached-images-b7087af3bf1d)  by Richard Durso:**

> To free up disk space use command **crictl images —prune,** sometimes it
> may not purge everything in use. It even purged the Kubernetes pause
> container image.
>
> **The kubelet flags are defined as :**
>
> **image-gc-high-threshold**: The percent of disk usage which triggers image garbage collection. Default is 85%.
>
> **image-gc-low-threshold:** The percent of disk usage to which image garbage collection attempts to free. Default is 80%.
>
> Configuring Kubernetes [Garbage Collection](https://The%20kubelet%20flags%20are%20defined%20as%20:%20%20%20image-gc-high-threshold:%20The%20percent%20of%20disk%20usage%20which%20triggers%20image%20garbage%20collection.%20%20Default%20is%2085%25.%20%20%20image-gc-low-threshold:%20The%20percent%20of%20disk%20usage%20to%20which%20image%20garbage%20collection%20%20attempts%20to%20free.%20Default%20is%2080%25.%20%20%20%20Configuring%20Kubernetes%20Garbage%20Collection%20should%20be%20your%20primary%20way%20to%20maintain%20disk%20space.%20%20However,%20you%20%20still%20use%20the%20CRI%20Purge%20script%20occasionally%20to%20review%20which%20images%20are%20cached%20%20and%20manually%20execute%20it%20when%20needed,%20such%20as%20while%20doing%20node%20maintenance%20before%20applying%20%20Ubuntu%20patches.%20%20You%20can%20try%20setting%20the%20ImagePullPolicy%20to%20IfNotPresent%20(spec.containers.imagePullPolicy:%20%20%22ifNotPresent%22)%20to%20ensure%20that%20the%20container%20image%20is%20only%20pulled%20from%20the%20registry%20if%20it%20is%20not%20already%20%20present%20on%20the%20node.%20This%20can%20help%20to%20start%20using%20local%20images%20cache%20and%20also%20prevent%20%20unauthorized%20images%20from%20being%20deployed%20to%20your%20cluster.%20%20%20%20%20%20Reference%20links:%20https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/18582%20%20%20%20%20%20https://serverfault.com/questions/1147668%20%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47867529) should be your primary way
> to maintain disk space. However, you  still use the **CRI Purge script**
> occasionally to review which images are cached and manually execute it
> when needed, such as while doing node maintenance before applying
> Ubuntu patches.

You can try setting the **ImagePullPolicy to** **IfNotPresent** (`spec.containers.imagePullPolicy: "ifNotPresent`") to ensure that the container image is only pulled from the registry if it is not already present on the node. This can help to start using local images cache and also prevent unauthorized images from being deployed to your cluster.

**EDIT-1**

You can mark the pause image not to be garbage collected by kubelet using the **pod-infra-container-image flag**, unique to the  "pause" image, provided by kubelet. This flag has two purposes: it helps avoid the occurrence of such problems by ensuring that the image is not cropped by the image garbage collector. Generally speaking, Kubelet shouldn't handle the "pause" container's trash collection. If this happens, there could be a number of underlying reasons for it, such as disk pressure causing the "pause" to be trash collected (as shown by commands such as "**df -h /var/lib..**").

For more information refer to this [Article](https://tickets.dominodatalab.com/hc/en-us/articles/15125607103124-failed-to-pull-image-602401143452-dkr-ecr-us-east-1-amazonaws-com-eks-pause-3-5) by Greg Hudson.

Comment: I have already add pod-infra-container-image but did not work.

Comment: Have you gone through this [gitlink](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/62388)  and also refer to  this similar  [stack link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46630377)  which may helpful to resolve your issue